# How to apply hyperlinks to URL text in existing HTML - UPDATED WITH JSFIDDLE & WORKING SOLUTION

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/daltontech/qfjr7e6a/ - Thanks to both that helped!

**Original question:**
I get JSON data from a report in my HelpDesk software that I import into an HTML table (via Python) & one of the columns is the address of the request, but it is not clickable.  I can edit the Python file (though I don't expect the answer is there) and the HTML file (and Javascript is both fine and expected to be the solution), but I cannot change the JSON data (much).

I can use JQuery, but if vanilla Javascript can do it, that is my preference.

I tried innerHTML (with and without global flag), but after about 20 rows, it fails spectacularly in IE & Chrome (all I tested) & this list is typically 50+.

I do use innerHTML successfully in other places, mainly linking technician names to their requests (a shorter list) like:

```
    { document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Jenny', '<a 
    href="https://helpdesk.domain.com/jenny">Jenny</a>'); }
```

Here's what I have to work with:

```
    <table class="Requests" id="Requests">
    <thead><tr><th>URL</th><th>Title</th><th>Technician</th></tr></thead>
    <tr><td>https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675309</td><td>I need a phone number</td><td>Jenny</td></tr>
    <tr><td>https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675310</td><td>Some other issue</td> 
    <td>John</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Everything before the number is always the same, so that gives some flexibility and I can have the JSON file provide a few options (just not the `<a>` tag...) like:
    1. 8675309
    2. https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675309
    3. sometext8675309
    4. sometext8675309someothertext

I'm hoping to accomplish either of the two row examples - either works, might prefer latter:

```
    <table class="Requests" id="Requests">
    <thead><tr><th>URL</th><th>Title</th><th>Technician</th></tr></thead>
    <tr><td><a href="https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675309">https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675309</a></td><td>I need a phone number</td><td>Jenny</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675310">link</a></td><td>Some other issue</td><td>John</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Commented Code:

```
// get the elements

document
  .querySelectorAll(".Requests > tbody > tr > td:first-child")

// for each element remove the text and
// replace it with an anchor tag
// use the original element's text as the link

.forEach(c => {
   let a = Object.assign(document.createElement("a"), {
      href: c.textContent,
      textContent: c.textContent
    });
    c.textContent = "";
    c.appendChild(a);
  });
```

### Example Snippet

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll(".Requests > tbody > tr > td:first-child")
  .forEach(c =>
    c.parentNode.replaceChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("a"), {
      href: c.textContent,
      textContent: c.textContent
    }), c)
  );
```

```html
<table class="Requests" id="Requests">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>URL</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Technician</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675309</td>
    <td>I need a phone number</td>
    <td>Jenny</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>https://helpdesk.domain.com/8675310</td>
    <td>Some other issue</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This mostly worked (and I appreciated getting to read it), but the a tag replaced the td tag, so while a completely unformatted table looks fine, any formatting is stripped.  Is there perhaps a type that I don't read javascript well enough to notice?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to use client-side JS to modify an already generated HTML table.

The below code works for me with +200 rows so I don't think using .innerHTML has an inherent issue, maybe there is something else causing your code to crash?

**EDIT (IE):**

```js
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('#Requests tr');

for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML = '<a href="' + rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0]
          .innerHTML + '">' + rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML + '</a>';
}
```

---

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('#Requests tr');

rows.forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      r.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML = '<a href="' + r.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML + '">' +  r.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML + '</a>'
    }

});
```

Comment: This worked great!  I'm breaking the rule regarding mentioning 'Thanks' because my reputation is too low for anyone to see I gave you an upvote :-)

Comment: Can this link two col?  I made the below change so I can just display the # and not the URL, but I might like a table with a list of reqs and a their assets (different URL+ number), but I have not figured out how I could either run the script twice (once each, two versions) or merge them into one single script.  I can get either column to link up, but not both.  I tried assigning an ID to each script, but that had no affect. `code` [0].innerHTML = '<a target="_top" title ="Request Link" href="https://helpdesk.domain.com/Request.do?woMode=viewWO&woID=' + r.getElementsByTagName('td')

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work in IE (not sure why I never tested it, but I did recently & I just took it back to scratch in jsfiddle, works great in Chrome, not at all in IE).

Comment: @Don Sorry I missed your comment, can you explain what you are trying to do with the 2 columns again? Also the IE issue is caused by the `.forEach` method, you can see my edit for an IE friendly version

Comment: You're awesome, that was the problem _(I was Googling the individual aspects of the script trying to determine which didn't have IE compatibility, but I hadn't found it)_.  The two column question was if I could do the same thing _(in concept, not content)_ to two different columns in the same table (maybe a column of requests and another of tasks).  Here's the current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daltontech/qfjr7e6a/6/

Comment: You could do it it to 2 separate columns. `rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0]` refers to the first column of `rows[i]` so you could add additional statements, refering to `('td')[2]` for instance to get the third column. Alternatively you could add a class or data attribute to all the table cells you want to modify (e.g. class `special-table-cell`). Then you could use `document.querySelectorAll('.special-table-cell')` to get an array of every element you are interested in.